# Testing normality

Tags: r, normal-distribution

How can I (in R) test whether the given data set is normally distributed? I read [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781798/seeing-if-data-is-normally-distributed-in-r)s suggesting `shapiro.test`. Unfortunately, according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test), the null-hypothesis is "data are normal".

I expect my data to be normal, hence I need a test whose null-hypothesis states "data are not normal" and with some level of certainty (e.g. 0.05) states that null-hypothesis doesn't hold.

What test should I use?

Comment: This is a question of statistical understanding, not programming, so I've voted to migrate it to CrossValidated.

Comment: You are using the correct test. You put in the null what you think is true.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492

Comment: @user603 ok but test may not be strong enough... how can I decide that?

Comment: @petrbel: I'm sorry I don't know where to start from. Have you read the links suggested by whuber? Maybe try to reformulate a new question in light of them

Comment: @user603 here it is, I hope it is more clear now - http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144236/reversed-shapiro-wilk